# Joining Tables with Django Rest Framework API

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I just want to know how to take two related database entities and send the desired joined data back as a single json response.

For instance, given the following files:

models.py

```
class Alpha(models.Model):
    alpha_id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    data = models.CharField(max_length = 255, null = True)

class Beta(models.Model):
    beta_id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    alpha_fk = models.ForeignKey(Alpha, null = True, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    data = models.CharField(max_length = 255, null = True)
```

serializers.py

```
class AlphaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Alpha
        fields = ('alpha_id','data')

class BetaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Beta
        fields = ('beta_id', 'alpha_fk', 'data')
```

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def AlphaDetailView(request, pk):
    try:
        modelObject = Alpha.objects.get(pk = pk)
    except Alpha.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status = 404)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = AlphaSerializer(modelObject)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = AlphaSerializer(modelObject, data = data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data)

        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status = 400)

    elif request.method == 'PATCH':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = AlphaSerializer(modelObject, data = data, partial = True)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data)

        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status = 400)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        modelObject.delete()
        return HttpResponse(status = 204)

@csrf_exempt
def BetaDetailView(request, pk):
    try:
        modelObject = Beta.objects.get(pk = pk)
    except Beta.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status = 404)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = BetaSerializer(modelObject)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = BetaSerializer(modelObject, data = data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data)

        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status = 400)

    elif request.method == 'PATCH':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = BetaSerializer(modelObject, data = data, partial = True)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data)

        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status = 400)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        modelObject.delete()
        return HttpResponse(status = 204)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^alpha/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', AlphaDetailView),
    url(r'^beta/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', BetaDetailView)
]
```

When I do a GET request on Alpha, I would like to be able to also get all of the fields in Beta which are related by the foreign key, effectively simulating an SQL join.

My coming here is in part a result of the fact that the DRF documentation I've found online seems very vague. Aside from digging through the source code, is there a place where I can go to see detailed information about the available objects and their built-in methods along with expected parameters and return types? All I've found is paragraph descriptions of what different objects do in a very general sense.